# XML Schema restriction based on other tag presense

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to define the restrictions for XML data through XML schema.

```
<person>
   <name>john</name>
   <username>johny</username>
   <password>secret</password>
</person>
```

Here clients can send the person data WITHOUT username/password , but if he wants to send he should send BOTH username/password?

Is it possible to restrict like this using XML schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<xs:choice>` and `<xs:sequence>`, first there is username & password, second there isn't